# Clearing collection before testing with Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I am writing unit tests for my Node.js app using Mocha, Chai, and Mongoose. The tests themselves work if the collection is empty(as desired), but I'm having trouble clearing the collection before testing.

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let Subject = require('../Subject/subject');

//Require the dev-dependencies
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
// let server = require('../server');
let server = "http://localhost:3000"
let should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('subjects', () => {
  before((done) => { //Before each test, empty the database
    Subject.remove({})
    done();         
  });

  describe('/GET subject', () => {
    // working test
  });

  describe('/POST subject', () => {
    // working test
  });

  describe('/GET subject', () => {
    // working test
  });
});
```

I have also tried variations of

```
Subject.deleteMany({}, (err) => console.log(err));
```

and

```
Subject.find({}, (subject)=>{
   subject.remove({}).exec()
})
```

inside the before block to no avail. I have tried the removes outside of the before block as well, just in case. If I `console.log(Subject.remove({}))` I get the Subject object, so it's able to access it, just not actually doing anything permanent with it.

I've been at this a couple hours now and haven't gotten any closer to figuring it out, so all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting for the callback of the remove call like so

```
before((done) => { //Before each test, empty the database
 Subject.remove({}, done);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both Mocha and Mognoose support promises for asynchronous blocks, they can be seamlessly used instead of calling `done` directly. In this case a promise should be returned:

```
  before(() => Subject.remove({}));
```

Comment: Trying this ends up causing a timeout error instead. I had that problem initially due to an incorrectly placed done() call.

Comment: It's understandable why incorrectly placed `done` causes an issue, but `remove` returns thenable when being used without a callback, it should work. This is how it's done in Mocha, https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises . There should be no `done` in this case. It's possible that `Subject.remove({}).exec()` may work, but I would expect it to work without `exec`.